# Right way to update a property from an object inside of array using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I already have a solution for this but I want to know how can be achieved with Ramda.
I have an array of objects which include this info:

```
{enabled: true
icon: "id"
id: "sectionId_1"
label: "Validación de identidad"
sectionNum: 1
status: "in-progress"
valid: false
}
```

So I want to update the enabled property to true.
My current solution is this:

```
const {
    sections: { flowSectionsById, flowSections }
  } = getState();

  const sections = pathOr({}, ['sections'], flowSections);
  const sectionsMap = map(identity, sections);
  const findCurrentSection = (id, list) => find(propEq('id', id), list);
  const findResult = findCurrentSection(flowSectionsById?.id, sectionsMap);
  const adjustStatus = lensProp('enabled');
  const result = set(adjustStatus, true, findResult);
  const transformSections = map(el => equals(el.id, result.id) ? result : el, sections);
  const clonedSections = clone(flowSections);
  const cloned = {
    current: inc(clonedSections.current),
    sections: transformSections
  }
```

where flowSections is the array that has all the objects from response and flowSectionsById is just my current section
FlowSections:

```
enabled: true
icon: "id"
id: "sectionId_1"
label: "Validación de identidad"
sectionNum: 1
status: "in-progress"
valid: false
__proto__: Object
1: {id: "sectionId_2", label: "Información personal", sectionNum: 2, status: "disabled", enabled: false, …}
2: {id: "sectionId_3", label: "Domicilio", sectionNum: 3, status: "disabled", enabled: false, …}
3: {id: "sectionId_4", label: "Co-firmantes", sectionNum: 4, status: "disabled", enabl
```

flowSectionsById:

```
enabled: true
icon: "id"
id: "sectionId_1"
label: "Validación de identidad"
sectionNum: 1
status: "in-progress"
valid: false
```

Comment: I see you're already using Ramda heavily in your snippet.  What is it you want to change?

Comment: Also, can you format your input data so that the JS parser can read it?  Are these last code blocks object, arrays, something else?